# Print a QR Code in JasperReports 5.6.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I get the following error when trying to print a QR code in *JasperReports*

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode("((java.lang.String)field_RECSEQ.getValue())",com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,300 ,150 )); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by adding the core.jar (*com.google.zxing:core*) and javase.jar (*com.google.zxing:javase*) to build path.

Comment: added all these libararies in maven but failed ot compile