# How to solve om.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to create a QR code in JasperSoft Studio.

We have a report properly working on production containing a QR code. But after a new installation of JasperSoft Studio, we are unable to run the report.

While compiling the report we are getting the error:

> com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type

Details:

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
    1. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    2. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    3. com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter cannot be resolved to a type
                    value = com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage( //$JR_EXPR_ID=38$
                            <---------------------------------------------->
    3 errors
    .

        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:229)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:289)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:141)

        at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportsBuilder.compileJRXML(JasperReportsBuilder.java:212)

        at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction.actionCompile(CompileAction.java:154)

        at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.action.CompileAction$1.run(CompileAction.java:98)

        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

We have setup the Java Build Path and added Core and JavaSE jars but the report doesn't compile.

[image]

[image]

The QR code is inserted in the report using the following expression :

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
    new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
        $F{QRCODE},
        com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 400
    )
)
```

[image]

How can I solve that?

### Comment on possible duplicates

The most similar question in SO is rather [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853682/print-a-qr-code-in-jasperreports-5-6-1), but no answer could be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the issue:

1. Download zxing.jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/z/Downloadzxingjavasejar.htm), if this link ever goes offline, I have a personal backup [here](https://mega.nz/file/tOoECZwa#GQHJvqI9aKYMBJKCfx20Is0RhzRMFIieyW8lQjQhyZY).
2. Add it to your project folder: [JAR added to Project Folder Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyscM.png)
3. Right click you project folder and Select [Build Bath > Configure Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tyj8.png)
4. Go to the [Libraries Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJfU0.png)
5. The should be 2 groups: ModulePath and Classpath, select Classpath and on the side panel, click [Add Jar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wuE0.png)
6. On the [Add JAR Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiOvQ.png), select you project folder where the jar is, select the jar and click OK.
7. Click on Apply and Close.

I was able to successfully compile my report with the QR Code after doing this.